# Assigning an integer to a dereferenced character pointer

Tags: c

```
int main(){
 char a = 5;
 char *p = &a;        // 8 bits
 int num = 123456789; // 32 bits
 *p = num;
 return 0;
}
```

As `a` is 1 byte and `num` is 4 bytes, does `*p = num` truncate num to 1 byte before assigning it to `a`? or a 32 bit value gets written to memory and corrupts the stack?

Comment: When you compiled this, what warnings did you get?

Comment: @MartinJames What warning do you mean this would generate?

Comment: didn't get any.

Comment: Then raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum. Do this always, and handle all issues reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're assigning an `int` value to a `char`, the value is converted in an implementation-defined way to be in the range of a `char` (most likely, the low order byte of `num` will be the value which is assigned).

The fact that you're dereferencing a `char *` to assign to a `char` doesn't change this.  It would be the same as if you did `a = num;`.

Comment: so when dereferencing a pointer and assigning a new value to it, it behaves as if we are assigning it to the original value, it gets truncated in this case.

Comment: @Dan Correct.  You would only have a problem if you attempted to cast the pointer to a different type and dereferenced the converted pointer, i.e. `*(int *)p = num;`

Comment: right, in ^ case it does corrupt the stack.

Comment: @Dan Not necessarily, it depends on the layout of the local variables. The compiler may have inserted some gap bytes to ensure alignment.